# Jquery clone/dragging

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem that I am hoping to get some help with. I have a drag and drop feature that works the way I want it but there is a small problem with it. Once I have dragged an image once, it won't let me drag the image again. I was wondering if someone could help me with getting the images to be dragged infinitely if possible. Thanks. Below is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#collectionArea").droppable({
        accept: ".selector",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $("#collectionArea .product").addClass("item");
            $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable selector");
            $("#cbOptions").show();
            $(".item").draggable({
                containment: "parent",
                grid: [72,72],
            });
        }
    });

    $(".selector").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        revertDuration: 1000,
        opacity: 0.75,
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out this line

//$(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable selector");

Your removing the selector class, and therefore $(".selector").draggable({
no longer has any effect

Comment: I deleted that line and I am still running into the same error. Do you think there is a conflict error with other jquery I have on the website? This problem has been driving me nuts.

Comment: I don't know, what other Jquery do you have on the site?

Comment: just some popups that take place on click functions. The thing is, these images have two jquery functions attached to them. On drag they can be dropped into the collection bin and on click would create a popup. Do you think the problem possibly lies there ?

Comment: That's possible. Maybe you should consider changing the popup on click to popup on mouseup, that way the popup action doesn't happen until you release the mouse button after you're done dragging.

Comment: I just took the other jquery out to test and still didn't work. This problem has baffled me. I have been trying to google the problem but I haven't be able to figure it out yet.